# Running Unity Hub behind the proxy

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, unity3d-mirror, zscaler

I am struggling to run the Unity 3D behind the proxy. Has any one got any success in doing so.
The issue could be due to firewall or zscaler certificates but Unity 3D doesn't provide any way to configure it.
I have faced similar situation with Android Studio as well and was able to fix it by adding the zscaler certificates to keystore but this is not the case with Unity 3D.

I kept getting this even on logging in to the unity hub:

[image]

Comment: i gave up.  So, i got hub working, but.. the editor package manager didnt use the same proxy settings so didnt work and it was like ive had enough, i spent ages having this setting for that and that for this.. and it was cant you get them to open the firewall, love, god himself probably couldnt pursuade them to do that, so no.. 1 dude wanting to run unity is not going to get that sorted.

Comment: @BugFinder i agree with your words..

Comment: before the did the hub and changed asset manager to be part of packagemanager, everything worked plenty well, yes, you had some funky issues getting bits from the asset store but you could.. because it used the basic web proxy.. but now? and worst is they (unity) know..

Answer (score 0):

try to use HTTP PROXY in environment variables

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).